# Front-derailleur bolt undoing: pliers and threadlocker

Tags: derailleur-front

When I unscrew the front derailleur bolt to adjust the cable (wrapping around B and C), the entire parallelogram rotates.

[image: Front derailleur bolt]

Part A: What is the appropriate way to unscrew the bolt?

1. Hold the parallelogram in place with a pair of pliers, or
2. Just rotate. The hinges in the front derailleur are designed to take the torque for removing/tightening the cable.

Part B: True or False: Since there is threadlocker applied to this bolt, there is no such a thing as a minor adjustment (unwind a little, set the cable right, wind back). The threadlocker must be re-applied, and so it's anyway necessary to first remove the bolt completely.

This is a [sequel](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/67336/48599) question.

Comment: I generally hold them with my hand and curses.  (I wouldn't normally use threadlocker on the bolt.)

Comment: @DanielRHicks I'm not sure whether you meant "... with my hand and curse" (because it's too easy to pinch one's fingers), or you were referring to some obscure (bike) tool.

Comment: Cursing is an important skill for any mechanic.

Comment: @Sam I think he means "curses" as in more than one curse. Many, many curses are required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just push the cage inward with your hand while undoing the bolt. Use a wad of rag to protect you hand or wear a heavy duty work glove. If you use a pair of pliers you'll scratch the finish.